# There is a way to use OpenLayers on Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, maps, openlayers

is There a way to use OpenLayers on Flex?
By now I've found Open-Scales project, but it is in development (not fully functional).

Answer (score 7):

We have recently released [OpenScales 1.1](http://openscales.org/) which has a lot of improvements and bugfixes compared to 1.0 beta release. There is a demo available on previous link.

OpenScales API have been designed to be quite close of OpenLayers one.
Since the beginning, the codebase has been extensively modified and
improved. Nevertheless, even if OpenScales API is not strictly
equivalent to OpenLayers one, if you have ever developed on
OpenLayers, you will find OpenScales API quite easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers is a pure JavaScript framework and I do not think that anyone has written a Flex wrapper for it. So the short answer is either "no" or "not easily".

That said, there are other Flex mapping clients available, depending on your needs.

- [ArcGIS Server Flex API](http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/flex/)
- Google Maps API
- Yahoo! Maps API

I don't use Flex, so I am not qualified to speak to the merits of each API but hopefully it can get you started. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[OpenScales](http://openscales.org/) is an LGPL ActionScript3 port of Openlayers.  It might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

OpenScales is really good, especially with the 1.2 release. However, it is a pretty small project and the support is not so good, so you're pretty much on your own if you get stuck.